# Merge two R data frames and identify the source of each row

Tags: r, merge

I am in a circumstance where I need to merge two data frames together that each contain one observation about a research subject. Unfortunately, the data capture system allowed the end-user to enter some variables on two screens (for instance, the gender was captured at two timepoints, and should not change). There are no database-side checks to confirm that the data is consistent between screens, so we are checking in the post-processing.

What I would *like* to do is use the built-in R `merge()` function to merge the data frames, with the `all=TRUE` option so that I get two rows where the shared variables do not match, and then to have a single column in the resultant data frame that tells me the source of the row (either from X or Y in the merge). As near as I can tell, there's nothing like that in the `merge()` function, so I am trying to write my own wrapper for `merge()` that will do this.

Example:

```
example_df1 <- data.frame(subject_id=c(101,102,103,104,105),
                          gender=c("M","F","M","M","F"),
                          weight=c(120,130,110,114,144),
                          score=c(10,12,11,13,11))

example_df2 <- data.frame(subject_id=c(101,102,103,104,105),
                          gender=c("M","M","M","M","F"),
                          weight=c(120,130,110,117,144),
                          site1=c(13,18,23,12,4),
                          site2=c(3,7,8,11,0),
                          site3=c(31,28,12,29,40))

merge(x=example_df1,y=example_df2,all=TRUE)

  subject_id gender weight score site1 site2 site3
1        101      M    120    10    13     3    31
2        102      F    130    12    NA    NA    NA
3        102      M    130    NA    18     7    28
4        103      M    110    11    23     8    12
5        104      M    114    13    NA    NA    NA
6        104      M    117    NA    12    11    29
7        105      F    144    11     4     0    40
```

Desired output:

```
  subject_id gender weight score site1 site2 site3 rowsource
1        101      M    120    10    13     3    31   both
2        102      F    130    12    NA    NA    NA    x
3        102      M    130    NA    18     7    28    y
4        103      M    110    11    23     8    12   both
5        104      M    114    13    NA    NA    NA    x
6        104      M    117    NA    12    11    29    y
7        105      F    144    11     4     0    40   both
```

I need to implement the solution in base R without any special packages if at all possible due to the regulatory environment surrounding the project. My initial thought is to try to use `intersect` to find the common variables between both `example_df1` and `example_df2`, and then to somehow compare each row of the merge result (within those common variables) against both `example_df1` and `example_df2` to figure out the source of the row. That seems really unwieldy, so I'd appreciate suggestions on how to improve the efficiency of this kind of task. Thanks!

EDITED TO ADD: If R always consistently puts the X row above the Y row in merges of this type, I suppose that could work too, but I think I'd feel better about something more stable than that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would just add another column *before* merging to make life easier:

```
example_df1$source <- "X"
example_df2$source <- "Y"
Merged <- merge(x = example_df1, y = example_df2,
                all = TRUE, by = c("subject_id", "gender", "weight"))
Merged$rowSource <- apply(Merged[c("source.x", "source.y")], 1, 
                          function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ""))
Merged
#   subject_id gender weight score source.x site1 site2 site3 source.y rowSource
# 1        101      M    120    10        X    13     3    31        Y        XY
# 2        102      F    130    12        X    NA    NA    NA     <NA>         X
# 3        102      M    130    NA     <NA>    18     7    28        Y         Y
# 4        103      M    110    11        X    23     8    12        Y        XY
# 5        104      M    114    13        X    NA    NA    NA     <NA>         X
# 6        104      M    117    NA     <NA>    12    11    29        Y         Y
# 7        105      F    144    11        X     4     0    40        Y        XY
```

From there, it should be easy to change `"XY"` to `"both"` if that is what you prefer in your output, and you can then drop the "source.x" and "source.y" columns....

Comment: Faster than me by a few seconds. Your answer is better anyway.

Comment: I feel like an idiot for not seeing this really simple solution. I had gone down a road like that one, but never thought of just using X and Y and pasting them together. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

this does it all in one merging step and does not modify the original data.frames

```
mm<-transform(merge(
    x=cbind(example_df1,source="x"),
    y=cbind(example_df2,source="y"),
    all=TRUE, by=intersect(names(example_df1), names(example_df2))),
    source=ifelse(!is.na(source.x) & !is.na(source.y), "both", 
        ifelse(!is.na(source.x), "x", "y")),
    source.x=NULL,
    source.y=NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again for the answers. Once I saw the solution of just using `cbind()` to attach the source variable to the data frame, it was easy. I wrote a simple function that does it, which I'm sharing here.

```
merge_with_source <- function(x,y,name.x="X",name.y="Y") {

    # Find the variables that the two data frames have in common
    merge.names <- intersect(names(x),names(y))

    # Next, attach a column to each data frame with the chosen name
    x.df <- cbind(x,datsrc=name.x)
    y.df <- cbind(y,datsrc=name.y)

    # Create a merged data frame on the common names
    merged.df <- merge(x=x.df,
                       y=y.df,
                       all=TRUE,
                       by=merge.names)

    # Eliminate NAs from the data source column
    merged.df[is.na(merged.df$datsrc.x),"datsrc.x"] <- ""
    merged.df[is.na(merged.df$datsrc.y),"datsrc.y"] <- ""

    # Paste the data source columns together to get a single variable
    # Then, note those that are "Both" by replacing the mangled name
    merged.df$datsrc <- paste(merged.df$datsrc.x,merged.df$datsrc.y,sep="")
    merged.df[merged.df$datsrc==paste(name.x,name.y,sep=""),"datsrc"] <- "Both"

    # Remove the data frame-specific variables
    merged.df$datsrc.x <- rm()
    merged.df$datsrc.y <- rm()

    return(merged.df)
}
```

Comment: That's an odd use of `rm()`. You seem to be relying on the fact that it will return `NULL` when that appears to be an undocumented "feature." It's probably safer to `<- NULL` explicitly.

Comment: I also might make the `by=` parameter of the merge a parameter of the function. Some times you don't want to merge on all the columns.

Comment: Hmm, I never thought about the `rm()` issue that way, but it's a good point. Thanks!