# Merge tables and indicate original table of observations

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 tables :

```
Inputs
Input1: Old Data Dictionary olddatadictionary.csv

       table       field type   description
1 MerzNisani       hisse LONG description 1
2 MerzNisani point_gisid LONG description 2
3    Polygon       gisid LONG description 3
4    Polygon  layer_type LONG description 4

Input2: New Data Dictionary newdatadictionary.csv

       table field  type
1 MerzNisani angle FLOAT
2 MerzNisani hisse  LONG
3    Polygon gisid  LONG
```

I want to join all rows and all columns from both old and new. Where there are not matching values, returns NA for the one missing. This could be done using dplyr `full_join()` function.

The issue is: I want to add a column to indicate from which table each observation has come from, as follows

```
Output
Output: Joined Dictionary

       table       field  type   description which_source
       (chr)       (chr) (chr)         (chr)        (chr)
1 MerzNisani       angle FLOAT            NA          new
2 MerzNisani       hisse  LONG description 1         both
3 MerzNisani point_gisid  LONG description 2          old
4    Polygon       gisid  LONG description 3         both
5    Polygon  layer_type  LONG description 4          old
```

I can add the (which_source) column but by some verbose code using if-else
statements. Is there any other solution using functional programming paradigm?
so that the code would be as clean and simple as possible and avoiding if-else and for-loops?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a column before merging seems to be the way to go:

[Merge two R data frames and identify the source of each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549605/merge-two-r-data-frames-and-identify-the-source-of-each-row)

For your example,

```
old$source <- "old"
new$source <- "new"
merged <- merge(old,new,all=T, by=c("table", "field", "type"))
merged$source <- apply(merged[,c("source.x","source.y")], 1, function(x) ifelse(length(na.omit(x))==2, "both", na.omit(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks fanli. This was very useful

Answer (score 0):

Building on @fanli's response, one additional way if you have to do this multiple times is to just define a new function that creates new variables and then uses these to create a source variable. One example might be:

```
table <- c("MerzNisani","MerzNisani","Polygon","Polygon")
field <- c("hisse","point_gisid","gisid","layer_type")
type <- c("LONG","LONG","LONG","LONG")
description <- c("description 1","description 2","description 3","description 4")
my.df1<-data.frame(table,field,type,description)

table <- c("MerzNisani","MerzNisani","Polygon")
field <- c("angle","hisse","gisid")
type <- c("FLOAT","LONG","LONG")
my.df2 <- data.frame(table,field,type)


full_join_source <-function(df1,df2,both_val="both"){

    #Create additional variables
    df1$temp.merge1 <- deparse(substitute(df1))
    df2$temp.merge2 <- deparse(substitute(df2))

    df_m <- full_join(df1,df2)

    #Get data source/sources
    df_m$source <- apply(df_m[c("temp.merge1","temp.merge2")],1,function(x) paste(na.omit(x),collapse=""))
    #Override source value when in both datasets
    df_m$source[nchar(df_m$source) == max(nchar(df_m$source))] <- both_val
    return(df_m[,!(names(df_m) %in% c("temp.merge1","temp.merge2"))])
}

my.fulljoin.df <- full_join_source(my.df1,my.df2,both_val="In Both")
```